# Python: Replace a string as variable in a file

Tags: python

If I have a file contents like this:

```
old_string
-old_string
```

I want to change only "old_string" to be "+new_string" so the result looks like

```
+new_string
-old_string
```

my code gives this result:

```
+new_string
-+new_string
```

This is my code :

```
    with open(filename) as f:

    s = f.read()

    if old_string not in s:

        return False

with open(filename, 'w') as f:

    s = s.replace(old_string, new_string)

    f.write(s)

    return True
```

i Tried regex, but it won't work since I pass the regex as a variables, this is what I did so far:

```
    with open (filename, 'r' ) as f:

       content = f.read()

content_new = re.sub('(\%old_string)', r'\new_string'%(old_string,new_string), content, flags = re.M)
```

Comment: You can probably write your own implementation of replace that checks if the previous char is a '-'.

Comment: @Adam - Would really appreciate it if you marked the answer that helped you solve your problem as the correct answer :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work for you:-

```
import re
with open("output.txt", "a") as myfile:

    with open('input.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            # print str(line)
            ret = re.sub(r"(\s|^|$)old_string(\s|^|$)",r" +new_string ",line) #It will replace if line contain 'old_string' by '+new_string'
            # print ret
            myfile.write(ret+'\n')
```

Note:- Check `output.txt`

Comment: where did you specify "old_string" ?

Comment: @Adam `Input string` is your `old string`.

Comment: @Adam,check I have update the ans try to run this by replacing your file name.

Comment: That seems to be fine, but if I have old_string after a word like for example options old_string. it returns it like options+new_string 
maybe I didn't explain it in my question

Comment: You only ask that it should replace exact match , if string is append or prepend by anything it should not that is what it's doing right?

Comment: Yes I tried it, it works fine if the old_string in the start of the sentence, but if it comes after a string as I explained, it mess it up.

Comment: @Adam, check the updated answer, It's working for me now

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is a bit off; you'll probably want to do something more like this:

```
import re

test_str = ("old_string\n"
            "-old_string")

match = "old_string"
subst = "+new_string"

regex = r"^{}".format(match)

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing
# the 4th argument

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix 
# the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

The `^` assertion in the pattern is something I recommend using, as it indicates the string to match should start at the very beginning of the line thus won't match `-old_string`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just ignore the lines which have a hyphen("-") at the beginning, and replace the rest.

The script below is a little different from yours. I have put in comments to help you understand. This should be easy to understand.

```
filename ="some_file"
output_filename = "some_other_file"

old_string = "old_string"
new_string = "+new_string"

input_file_handle = open(filename,"r") # File being opened in read mode
output_file_handle = open(output_filename, "w") # File being opened in write mode

# Read in input file line by line
for line in input_file_handle:

    # Write to output file and move on to next line
    if old_string not in line:
        output_file_handle.write(line+"\n")
        continue

    # This line contains the old_string. We check if it starts with "-". 
    # If it does, write original line and move on to next line
    if line.startswith("-"):
        output_file_handle.write(line+"\n")
        continue


    # At this stage we are absolutely sure we want to replace this line's contents
    # So we write the replaced version to the new file
    output_file_handle.write(new_string+"\n")


# Close both file handles
input_file_handle.close()
output_file_handle.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

A benefit to my solution is that it does not rely on the "do-not-replace" prefix being at the beginning of the line.

If you wanted to solve this problem without regular expressions you could write your own replace method:

`replace.txt`:

```
old_string
-old_string

old_string -old_string --old_string old_string
```

`replace.py`:

```
import sys
import fileinput

def replace_exclude(string, search, replace="", excluding_char='-'):
    # Does replace unless instance in search string is prefixed with excluding_char.
    if (not string) or (not search): return None
    for i in range(len(string)):
        while string[i-1] == excluding_char:
            i += 1
        if i < len(string):
            for j in range(len(search)):
                possible = True
                if not (string[i + j] == search[j]):
                    possible = False
                    break
        if possible:
            string = string[0:i] + replace + string[i+len(search):]
            i += len(replace)
    return string

filename = "replace.txt"

for line in fileinput.input([filename], inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write(replace_exclude(line, "old_string", "+new_string"))
```

`replace.txt` after running `replace.py`:

```
+new_string
-old_string

+new_string -old_string --old_string +new_string
```

Comment: Hey Greg, Would that work for python 2.7 ?
I get error in     print(replace_exclude(line, "old_string", "+new_string"), end='')

Comment: Oh, no I develop in Python 3, and I recommend you upgrade to it. If you want specific answers in the old, outdated, legacy Python 2, then you should tag your question specifically `python2.x` or `python2.7`.

Comment: As an aside, I should say that my claim that Python 2 is legacy should be backed by evidence: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Comment: I edited my answer to include Python 2.7 support by using `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`. The actual `replace_exclude` method didn't need to change, just the method of writing out.